# Como repetir uma notificação de minuto a minuto

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Estou criando uma *app* simples que recebe uma notificação toda vez que eu clico num botão do meu *layout*, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Agora quero que essa notificação fique repetindo por exemplo a cada minuto ate eu desactivar a mesma. Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como posso fazer isso?? :).

Aqui está o meu código.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);
        Button createNotification = (Button) findViewById
                (R.id.create_notification_button);
        createNotification.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this ,
                        notificationActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                        (MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification notification = new Notification.Builder (MainActivity.this)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_notification))
                        .setContentText(getString (R.string.notification_content))
                        .setSmallIcon (R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .getNotification();
                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify (0, notification);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um serviço que recorrendo a um HandlerThread usa o Handler para lançar as notificações periodicamente.

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private Handler handler;

    //Define o tempo entre notificações, altere como quiser
    private final int TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS = 10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("NotifyService","onCreate");

        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("NotifyService","onStart");

        //Previne que seja executado em subsequentes chamadas a onStartCommand
        if(!handlerThread.isAlive()) {
            Log.d("NotifyService","Notificações iniciadas");
            handlerThread.start();
            handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendNotification();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS);
                }
            };
            handler.post(runnable);
        }
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("NotifyService","Notificações terminadas");
        handlerThread.quit();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void sendNotification(){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this ,
                notificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder (this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_notification))
                .setContentText(getString (R.string.notification_content))

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .getNotification();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify (0, notification);
        Log.d("NotifyService", "notificação enviada");
    }
}
```

Declare o serviço no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    ...
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".NotifyService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Para iniciar a criação das notificações use:

```
startService(new Intent(this, NotifyService.class));
```

As notificações serão lançadas com o intervalo de tempo indicado em `TEMPO_ENTRE_NOTIFICAÇOES_SEGUNDOS`, mesmo que sai da aplicação.

Para parar as notificações use:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, NotifyService.class))
```

Exemplo com dois botões, um para iniciar e outro para parar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startNotification = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_notification_button);
        Button stopNotification = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_notification_button);

        startNotification.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifyService.class));
            }
        });

        stopNotification.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifyService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu...Vou dar analisar o código qualquer duvida eu aviso...

Comment: fiz todas as modificações recomendadas por si no entrando ao fazer click não entra nenhuma notificação. No 
Logcat pararece a seguinte mensagem "Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.".

Comment: O código foi testado antes de o postar. Não entendo essa mensagem neste contexto, já que o código do serviço(lançar a notificação) não corre na *main thread*. Teste o serviço com a Activity exemplo que postei.

Comment: usei a activity exemplo e nas linhas  .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_notification))
.setContentText(getString (R.string.notification_content)) aparecerem com erro no new_notification e no notification_content. O que devo fazer ai??

Comment: Esse é o código que cria a notificação, ele foi copiado da sua pergunta. É suposto que esses *string resources* tenham sido criados por si. Para teste pode substituir `getString(R.string.xxxx)` por `"qualquer coisa"`

Comment: Retirei o erro mas continua sem enviar nenhuma notificação... Se poder envie o projeto que vc chegou a testar para o meu email por favor... oliveira.ianik@hotmail.com

Comment: Você declarou o serviço no *AndroidManifest.xml*?

Comment: Sim cheguei a declarar..

Comment: Note que ele tem de ser declarado dentro da *tag* `<application>`.

Comment: @Amaral vc é o cara, acontece que eu tinha aberto outra tag aplication e não tinha dado conta. Agora tá funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigada pela ajuda e pela paciência.

Comment: Passando pra deixar um +1. =D

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, porém você pode usar o [**`ScheduledExecutorService`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) em um `Service`. Veja como ficaria:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    // definição do loop de 60 em 60 segundos, equivalente a 1 min
    private static final int SECONDS = 60 ;

    // indica inicilização
    int mStartMode;

    //interface para clientes
     IBinder mBinder;

    //indica se o onRebind está sendo usado
    boolean mAllowRebind;

    private ScheduledExecutorService sTaskExecutor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Serviço iniciado!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!sTaskExecutor.isShutdown()) {
            sTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    /* aqui você insere a notificação  */
                    android.util.Log.wtf(MyService.class.getSimpleName(), " Em loop!!!");
                }
            }, 0, SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        return mStartMode;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return mAllowRebind;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        sTaskExecutor.shutdown();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Serviço finalizado!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

No *Manifest*:

```
<application>
    ...
     <service android:name=".MyService" android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

Para **INICIAR** o `Service` user o método `startService` na sua classe `MainActivity`. Veja:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
```

Para **PARAR** o `Service` user o método `stopService`. Veja:

```
stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
```

Para mais detalhes, você pode [ver na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: essa classe continua executando mesmo após o app ser minimizado ou fechado?

Comment: vou dar uma olhada na documentação Ack Lay ... Valeu

Comment: Mr_Anderson funciona só quando eu faço click no botão.

Comment: Sim pretendo receber notificações quando o app estiver funcionando em background tambem..

Comment: Como se pode desactivar as notificações?

Comment: Pára o serviço, mas as notificações continuarão a ser lançadas.

Comment: Vi que editou a resposta mas, apesar das notificações deixarem agora de ser lançadas, o *runnable* continuará a ser executado. O serviço, apesar do método `onDestroy()` ser chamado, não poderá "ser limpo" pelo GC, porque o *runnable* tem uma referência a ele.

Comment: Havia a questão de garantir que, se o método `onStartCommand()` fosse novamente chamado, não fosse criado um novo Task. Penso que `if (!sTaskExecutor.isShutdown()) ` resolve esse problema. Só acho que usar um ScheduledExecutorService é um pouco exagerado para a terefa em causa. No entanto vou dar +1.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar também o `AlarmManager` para gerenciar o envio das notificações.

Primeiro crie uma classe que extenda `BroadcastReceiver`

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DispararNotificacao extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // faz o que vc precisa aqui para disparar sua notificação
    }
}
```

Depois só adicionar o pedido ao `AlarmManager` dentro do seu `onClick`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DispararNotificacao.class);

PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 
    requestCode, tarefaIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

final long inteval = minuto * 60 * 1000;

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
    inteval, tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Para desativar as notificações é só cancelar no `AlamrManager`

```
Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DispararNotificacao.class);
PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 
    requestCode, tarefaIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Usar um AlarmManager para lançar eventos de minuto a minuto é algo desaconselhado. Ver [nota](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) na documentação.

Comment: Christian Beregula daria para me mostrar um exemplo??

Comment: ramaral então o que poderia ficar bem nessa situação??

Comment: @YanikSantos Irei colocar uma resposta.

Comment: Fico aguardando então...